# Selenium TimeoutException when trying to find and click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to fill a form and click submit

Been able to fill text boxes/select radio button etc but when trying to click on the submit button, it gives me below exception

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\submitemail.py", line 81, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='submit']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Code I am trying is below

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='submit']"))).click()
```

Tryied putting manual sleep before executing this line as well but with the same error

Comment: could yo uadd full stack out put and what happendd s when you simply give element.click()

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML

Comment: @PDHide: I added the full exception message

Answer (score 1):

I used `execute_script` instead first approach and this has solved the problem

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='submit']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```